# How to determine which component adds -L/usr/lib to the gcc compile command?

Tags: debugging, gcc, command-line, linker, g++

I have an Autotools project which generates one of those long link command, with about 30 libs. For some reason, an -L/usr/lib appeared in the link command, even though all my libraries are installed in /usr/lib64. The compilation still works, but the links first looks in the wrong dir, and generates the corresponding warnings.

I already checked all the pkgconfig files (*.pc) of the libraries for wrong paths, but did not find any problems.
Even ran pkg-config on each of the libraries - no luck.

Of course, many of those libraries then pull in other libraries...

The question: Is there some 'organized' way to deduce where that option comes from? Maybe some command I'm
unaware of?

Comment: before your run your `configure` or `make` command, see if `/usr/lib` is already in  your environment with `set | grep '/usr/lib'` and `export | grep '/usr/lib'`. If its in that output, (as I'm guessing it will be), then it is one of the default `.profile` files that get sourced when you start your shell. Consult you `man bash|ksh|csh` for what files get autmatically sourced. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @shelter. No such luck though. I continually compile programs and this would have jumped up long ago. I'm guessing - though I haven't found it yet - that it might be in one of the .la files that get consulted. My .profile, .bashrc etc are all quite clean.

Comment: Use `strace` on autotools to see which commands are called with what arguments.

Comment: Hi n.m.! I was afraid of doing that - with some reason :) I've added an answer below with some more details. Maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you something queries a 32-bit tool, or queries a multiarch tool(GCC?) without passing the option to set it to 64-bit ?  Does your gcc default generate 64-bit binaries?

Comment: Hallo Marco. Yes... Though the system has the compatibility libraries installed, I rarely create 32 bit executables (kept those libs around because of 32bit versions of wine). I take care that all the components get installed correctly, including the .pc, .la files... Gcc and friends are of course 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Well. I had loads of other things over the last few days. but finally found some time to dedicate again. Though I had thought about it early on, I was afraid it would be more work than warranted: I frequently use strace to follow the needs of a program, but I was afraid that the entire compilation process would be to large to tackle. N.m.'s suggestion (above) pushed me back in that direction.

First, looking at the verbose output of 'make V=1', I noticed that only the libtool link command had to be traced, which probably saved me a load of work. I copied the link command to command line, and sure enough, the same error came out.

Then I redirected the strace output to a file, and had 28k lines to search through. I guess I got lucky, and around line 12000, I found a reference to libFLAC.la, containing -L/usr/lib, and then in libsndfile too, probably pulled in from the same libFLAC.la. I edited both, and had a clean compile! Maybe we should get rid of those .la files...

Thanks to n.m., and to strace, which so frequently saves me.